# Reducing arrow size of mat-paginator without using ng-deep

Tags: angular-material, ng-deep

I have used mat-paginator in my project
and wanted to reduce size of pagination arrows **without using ng-deep**

[screenshot of mat-paginator result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnvxM.png)

Currently I am able to do it with following code:

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-icon {
    width: 3vh;
    margin-top: -0.5vh;
  }
```

But have to do it without using ng-deep!
Any suggestions?

I tried **encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None**
and achieved results but that's affecting/disordering other UI features on that web page

Comment: It's very surprising to me that you are using the unit `vh` to change the width of the icon. This means that depending on the height of the viewport, the icon will have different sizes. For example, on a mobile phone in landscape mode, the icon will be barely visible. I would recommend to use `px` unit.

Comment: @JSON Derulo thanks
Sure, will do it

but please give some suggestion on how can I reduce arrow size of mat-paginator without using ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

add some class to your mat-paginator something like

```
<mat-paginator class="a-c"></mat-paginator>
```

then in your global `style.css` use this class to apply styles

```
.a-c .mat-paginator-icon {
    width: 3vh;
    margin-top: -0.5vh;
  }
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if this would work. The paginator icon is inside the `mat-paginator` component, so also in your example I strongly believe you need to use `::ng-deep`.

Comment: I tried it sir, but it didn't worked

Comment: @SaadAli have you added the styles in style.css if so can you can stackblitz example for the same

Comment: @JSONDerulo should work as style.css styles are global not component related

Comment: @SaadAli working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-paginator-a7h1dj?file=styles.css

Comment: You're right, in styles.scss there is no view encapsulation, so this works.